# How to Hide API_KEY in browser's Source Code?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I'm sending an **API_KEY** from the server to the client side, and at client side I'm using JavaScript/jquery.

How can I protect my API_KEY so that no one can see this API_KEY by "Right Click-> View Page Source" in js Part?

Comment: You can't do that, anything which is at client side can be seen by user some or other way. And Java != Javascript

Comment: You can at most obfuscate it which will make it more or less difficult to retrieve for the standard user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this as the previous answers say. So your best bet here is to:

1. Make sure what you send can't be abused (IE: Don't send a sensitive key, but maybe a temporary reference to it?)
2. Find another way to solve the same problem. Often you can solve these kind of problems by moving your logic to the server/backend, so no sensitive information needs to leave the server.

More info would be great if you want any spesific suggestions.